# Create an array of arrays of equivalent value

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, methods, nested

Here is the array:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 4, 591, 392, 391, 2, 5, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1, 20, 20]
```

How can I achieve the following output?

```
output: // [[1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], 4, 5, 10, [20, 20], 391, 392, 591]
```

Thanks for any help provided!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a basic 'group by' and then flatten any arrays in the result with length 1.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 4, 591, 392, 391, 2, 5, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1, 20, 20];

const result = Object.values(arr
  .reduce((a, c) => ((a[c] ??= []).push(c), a), {}))
  .map(a => a.length > 1 ? a : a[0]);

console.log(result);
```

The sorting that is seen in the output is a result of of javascript object property ordering which sorts integer keys first in ascending order, followed by non-integer keys in insertion order, see: [Does JavaScript guarantee object property order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order).

If you don't want to rely on the implicit sorting provided by the Object you can explicitly `sort()` the input before reducing it directly into an array. Here using a closure over a temporary 'group' array `g` to hold a reference to the current grouping.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 4, 591, 392, 391, 2, 5, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1, 20, 20];

const result = [...arr]
  .sort((a, b) => a - b)
  .reduce(
    (g => (a, c, i, { [i - 1]: p }) => ((c !== p && a.push(g = [])), g.push(c), a))(),
    [],
  )
  .map(a => a.length > 1 ? a : a[0]);
    
console.log(result);
```

##### Edit

The same logic as the above can be implemented in a more transparent way using a [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop with explicit checks for properties instead of using [nullish coallescing assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment)

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 4, 591, 392, 391, 2, 5, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1, 20, 20];

const grouped = {};

for (const element of arr) {
  if (grouped[element] === undefined) {
    grouped[element] = [];
  }

  grouped[element].push(element);
}

const result = Object.values(grouped)
  .map(a => a.length > 1 ? a : a[0]);

console.log(result);
```

The second example can also be expanded to use a simple `for...of` loop thus making the logic more transparent.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 4, 591, 392, 391, 2, 5, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1, 20, 20];

const sorted = [...arr].sort((a, b) => a - b);

const grouped = [];
let group;
for (const [i, current] of sorted.entries()) {
  const previous = sorted[i - 1];
  if (current !== previous) {
    group = [];
    grouped.push(group);
  }
  group.push(current);
}

const result = grouped.map(a => a.length > 1 ? a : a[0]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hey @Pilchard, thanks a ton for all the examples! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
let array = [1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 5, 6, 4, 4];
array.sort((a, b) => a > b);

const result = [];
while(array.length > 0) {
  const firstEl = array[0];
  array.splice(0,1);
  const current = [firstEl];
  for(let x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
    if(array[x] == firstEl) {
      current.push(array[x]);
      array.splice(x, 1);
    }
  }
  result.push(current);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hey @Fabrizio, thanks so much for the help man! Unfortunately the output from your code isn't matching the output I need

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 4, 591, 392, 391, 2, 5, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1, 20, 20]

result = [
    ...arr
        .sort((x, y) => x - y)
        .reduce(
            (m, x) => m.set(x, (m.get(x) ?? 0) + 1),
            new Map
        )
].map(
    ([x, n]) => n === 1 ? x : Array(n).fill(x))

console.log(...result)
```

This produces what you're looking for, however that unpacking looks really ugly. How about a small utility function?

```
Object.prototype.tap = function (fn, ...args) {
    return fn(this, ...args)
}

//    

result = arr
    .sort((x, y) => x - y)
    .reduce(
        (m, x) => m.set(x, (m.get(x) ?? 0) + 1),
        new Map
    )
    .tap(Array.from)
    .map(
        ([x, n]) => n === 1 ? x : Array(n).fill(x))
```

Comment: why mutate the Object prototype? Especially for a beginner that is a terrible idea.

Comment: @pilchard: what exactly is "terrible" about it?

Comment: plenty of discussion already on SO (ie [Why is extending native objects a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice)), but in general makes the code less transportable outside of a given codebase. Why not just declare a helper function rather than attaching it to the Object.prototype?

Comment: A helper function wouldn't be chainable, which is the whole point.